# custom meta field at run time

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type, custom-fields

I have created a meta field in my custom post type to input from user. Now i want if the user in the admin panel wants to create another meta field by pressing the add button then one another meta field is created. If the user presses many times the button then many meta fields should be created. I have searched a lot for this to create meta field at run time without plugin but cant too much find about it.

**Code**

```
 function Print_price_fileds($cnt, $p = null) {
  if ($p === null){
   $a = $b = $c = '';
 }
 else{
   $a = $p['n'];
   $b = $p['d'];
   $c = $p['p'];
 }
return  <<<HTML
<li>
<label>Nr :</label>
<input type="text" name="price_data[$cnt][n]" size="10" value="$a"/>

<label>Description :</label>
<input type="text" name="price_data[$cnt][d]" size="50" value="$b"/>

<label>Price :</label>
<input type="text" name="price_data[$cnt][p]" size="20" value="$c"/>
<span class="remove">Remove</span>
 </li>
HTML
;
}


//add custom field - price
add_action("add_meta_boxes", "object_init");

function object_init(){
add_meta_box("price_meta_id", "Price fields :","price_meta", "services",   "normal", "low");

 }

 function price_meta(){
 global $post;
  $data = get_post_meta($post->ID,"services",true);
  //echo '<pre>'; var_dump($data); exit(0);
  echo '<div>';
 echo '<ul id="price_items">';
 $c = 0;
 if (count($data) > 0){
    foreach((array)$data as $p ){
        if (isset($p['p']) || isset($p['d'])|| isset($p['n'])){
            echo Print_price_fileds($c,$p);
            $c = $c +1;
        }
    }

 }
 echo '</ul>';

 ?>
    <span id="here"></span>
    <span class="add"><?php echo __('Add Price Data'); ?></span>
    <script>
        var $ =jQuery.noConflict();
            $(document).ready(function() {
            var count = <?php echo $c - 1; ?>; // substract 1 from $c
            $(".add").click(function() {
                count = count + 1;
                $('#price_items').append('<li><label>Nr :</label><input type="text" name="price_data[' + count + '][n]" size="10" value=""/><label>Description :</label><input type="text" name="price_data[' + count + '][d]" size="50" value=""/><label>Price :</label><input type="text" name="price_data[' + count + '][p]" size="20" value=""/><span class="remove">Remove</span></li>');
               $('#price_items').append('<? echo implode('',explode("\n",Print_price_fileds('count'))); ?>'.replace(/count/g, count));
                return false;
            });
            $(".remove").live('click', function() {
                $(this).parent().remove();
            });
        });
    </script>
    <style>#price_items {list-style: none;}</style>
  <?php
  echo '</div>';
  }


 //Save product price
 add_action('save_post', 'save_detailss');

 function save_detailss($post_id){ 
 global $post;


   // to prevent metadata or custom fields from disappearing... 
   if ( defined('DOING_AUTOSAVE') && DOING_AUTOSAVE ) 
   return $post_id; 
  // OK, we're authenticated: we need to find and save the data
   if (isset($_POST['price_data'])){
    $data = $_POST['price_data'];
    update_post_meta($post_id,'price_data',$data);
}else{
    delete_post_meta($post_id,'price_data');
 }
}
```

Comment: it is not getting into the script portion

Comment: You mean something like [the repeater field](http://madebydenis.com/wordpress/adding-related-pages-and-links-in-your-articles/)? This can be customized to your liking ofc, but from what you've described sounds like a repeater field to me...

Comment: yes it is a repeater field. mean i have created one custom field. it will have a add new field button. when user clicks on it a new custom meta field should create

Comment: Then just follow the tutorial I created and just modify it a bit to suit your needs. In my case I'm adding links, but if you want a simple text field then it's even simpler ;)

Comment: @dingo_d i have found the above code from somewhere else question. i want just one image field. and if user wants multipe image then he can clicks on the add new and one more image field should be created

Comment: where is the tutorial ..that i can follow

Comment: I've linked the repeater field sentence in the comment. Just click on it :)

Comment: yes i also wants link of the image or it can be text field

Comment: ok sir i will see the tutorial now.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108137/discussion-between-waqas-jr-developer-and-dingo-d).

Comment: @dingo_d sir it is a very complex. i just need one field that can add value tin the database when the post is published

Comment: Well repeater fields are a bit complex. What you need is not a trivial thing I'm afraid, you need some coding knowledge. You could try seeing if Advanced Custom Fields have something like what you need.

Comment: It is a plugin. i dont want to use plugin sir

Comment: i simply want a text field e.g enter your city. user can enter city name. if he wants to enter one more city name then he can press the add button and one more field is created.

Comment: this article is complex one. it involves url. editer pop up etc etc

Comment: i have done this work with plugin before but i dont want to do it with plugins now

Comment: I said that you'll need to modify it a bit. I'm using input fields to add url's and pages, you'll need to add url of your image.

Comment: it will be added. but what if i need to get it in my page.

Comment: if you have a specif article or example related to it then please share it with me

Comment: I'm afraid this is all I have atm...

Comment: ok sir thanks for ur time and help

Comment: Sorry I couldn't be of more help, but it's worth investing some time to figure out how the repeater works :)

Comment: yes i will try my best to use it according to my needs

Comment: i have done that ..but now there is a issue that how will i get these values in single.php

Comment: @dingo_d can you just tell that how can i get this

Comment: Well just look in the post meta that you've saved with [get_post_meta()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_meta/)

Comment: i want these values in another function

Comment: @dingo_d http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36399161/not-getting-the-custom-field-value

Comment: You still need to get it using `get_post_meta()` function. Just specify the post id and meta value...

Comment: $meta1 = get_post_meta( get_the_ID() );
 //$meta = unserialize($post_meta['repeatable_fields'][0]);
    $meta= unserialize($meta1['repeatable_fields'][0]);
 echo "<pre>"; var_dump($meta);
 echo $meta->repeatable_fields;
 $new = array();
 $names = $meta['repeatable_fields'];
 $count = count( $names );
 echo "<pre>"; var_dump($count);
 for ( $i = 0; $i < $count; $i++ ) {
  if ( $names[$i] != '' ) :
   $new[$i]['article_name'] = stripslashes( strip_tags( $names[$i] ) );
  endif;
 }

Comment: `$post_meta = get_post_meta($post->ID);` inside the loop

Comment: i Have done it.thanks alor sirr

Comment: can we take image input here and get a image